# What happens to the opened file object inside a Python generator expression?

Tags: python, generator-expression

My question is, what happens to the file object created inside a generator expression after the generator's iterator is exhausted? Has `close` been called on it? or this benefit only comes while reading file using `with` statement?

## Example

```
my_file = (nth_row for nth_row in open(file_path, "rt"))

while True:
    try:
        print(next(my_file))

    except StopIteration:
        print("End of the file")
        break
```

Comment: The file object is not closed unless it is closed by explicitly calling `.close()` on it or it is implicitly called by exiting a `with` statement block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `close()` method is not called. Generator expressions don't behave like with statements; they don't care whether you use a context manager. The code may result in a memory leak. Generally, the garbage collector will close the file, but that's not guaranteed. You could wrap the whole thing in a with block:

```py
with open(file_path, "rt") as file:
    my_file = (nth_row for nth_row in file)
    
    while True:
        try:
            print(next(my_file))
    
        except StopIteration:
            print("End of the file")
            break
```

If you want to read the file in chunks, see [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/519633/19846219)? You can replace the `.read(chunk_size)` with `readline()` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it explicitly like this:

```
file = open(file_path, "rt")

my_file = (nth_row for nth_row in file)

while True:
        try:
                print(next(my_file))

        except StopIteration:
                print("End of the file")
                print(f"File closed in the current process: {file.closed}")
                break
```

the file object is still open (in the current process).